# Python script crashing but only when run from post request

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have a post request to spawn a child process to run my discord_bot.py script and pass it a variable.

When I run the script from the terminal it runs fine. However, when I run it via the post route in my Node.js app it always crashes at a particular point.

I've posted below:

1. Post route code from my server.js file.
2. Code from my discord_bot.py script, **!!!!!!!** at point of failure.
3. Errors I'm getting in the console.

### Post route from server.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const discordbot = require("./config/discordbot.js");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require("axios");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const spawner = require("child_process").spawn;
const promptCommand = "test output command";

app.post("/runPythonScript", (req, res) => {
    const pythonProcess = spawner("python", [
        path.join(__dirname, "public/py/discord_bot.py"),
        promptCommand,
    ]);
    console.log("Data sent to python script:", promptCommand);
    pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
        console.log("Data send back from python script:", data.toString());
        res.json({ message: "Python script is running" });
    });
    });
```

### Code from discord_bot.py with **!!!!!!!** at point of failure.

```
import sys
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.relative_locator import locate_with
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


# Initialize the browser instance
# path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/mrthe/bootcamp/pydiscordbrowser/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless=False')


# Navigate to Discord
driver.get('https://discord.com/login')
time.sleep(2)

# Find the email and password fields and fill 'em in
time.sleep(2)
dlEMAIL = os.getenv('dlEMAIL')
dlPASSWORD = os.getenv('dlPASSWORD')

jxEMAIL = os.getenv('jxEMAIL')
jxPASSWORD = os.getenv('jxPASSWORD')

jxPyEMAIL = os.getenv('jxPyEMAIL')
jxPyPASSWORD = os.getenv('jxPyPASSWORD')

email_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'email')
email_field.send_keys(jxPyEMAIL)
password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password')
password_field.send_keys(jxPyPASSWORD)


# Find the login button on the login form and click it
time.sleep(1)
loginButton = driver.find_element(locate_with(By.TAG_NAME, "div").above({
    By.CLASS_NAME: "needAccount-MrvMN7"}).below({By.CLASS_NAME: "contents-3ca1mk"}))
loginButton.click()
print("##### Made it through login process")
sys.stdout.flush()


# Navigate to server and channel via URL
time.sleep(5)
driver.get("https://discord.com/channels/1063538236[REDACTED]/106353823690[REDACTED]")
print("##### Made it to the proper channel in the DL server")
sys.stdout.flush()

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

# Post in the channel
time.sleep(3)
# Get the active element
active_element = driver.execute_script("return document.activeElement")
print("##### got active element via script execution")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(3)
# Print the element to the console
print(active_element.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
print("#### printed active element to console")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(3)

# Send input to the active element

print("##### made it to first prompts variables blocks")
sys.stdout.flush()
text1 = "test output 1"
text2 = "test output 2"
text3 = "test output 3"

data_to_send_back = "Message from python script: Hello."
print("##### made it to commented out inputs/outputs")
sys.stdout.flush()
input = sys.argv\[1\]
output = data_to_send_back
print(output)

sys.stdout.flush()
print("##### made it to the send_keys list")
sys.stdout.flush()
active_element.send_keys(text1)
time.sleep(300/1000)
active_element.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
time.sleep(300/1000)
active_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

### ERRORS in terminal

```
[29220:31768:0118/170808.365:ERROR:cert_issuer_source_aia.cc(34)] Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

Data send back from python script: ##### Made it to the proper channel in the DL server

node:_http_outgoing:644
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

## Things I've Tried

1. 

---

I thought maybe there was something wrong with the way I called the argument, so to test I cut out the following block entirely.

```
sys.stdout.flush()
input = sys.argv[1]
output = data_to_send_back
print(output)
```

This did not change the behavior. The script still crashes at exactly the same point (marked by **!!!!!!!** in the code above).

However, if I run the script from the terminal instead of the post route, it runs perfectly fine. Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

### 2.

I implemented Michael M's suggestion from his commented and updated my post route code as below.

```
app.post("/runPythonScript", async (req, res) => {
    const pythonProcess = spawner("python", [
        path.join(__dirname, "public/py/discord_bot.py"),
        promptCommand,
    ]);
    console.log("Data sent to python script:", promptCommand);

    let data = "";
    pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", (part) => (data += part));
    await new Promise((resolve) => pythonProcess.stdout.on("close", resolve));

    console.log("Data send back from python script:", data.toString());
    res.json({ message: "Python finished", data: data });
});
```

We've made progress, in that I'm getting different errors in the terminal now, but the script is still crashing at the same point.

These are the errors I'm receiving now.

```
Error parsing cert retrieved from AIA (as DER):
ERROR: Couldn't read tbsCertificate as SEQUENCE
ERROR: Failed parsing Certificate

Data send back from python script: ##### Made it through login process
##### Made it to the proper channel in the DL server
##### got active element via script execution
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your server. Your `pythonProcess.stdout.on("data"` handler can run multiple times with new data each time, but you can only call `res.json()` once because, as the error says, it sets headers. Try using a promise and the `"close"` event instead:

```js
app.post("/runPythonScript", async (req, res) => {
    const pythonProcess = spawner("python", [
        path.join(__dirname, "public/py/discord_bot.py"),
        promptCommand,
    ]);
    console.log("Data sent to python script:", promptCommand);

    let data = "";
    pythonProcess.stdout.on("data", part => data += part);
    await new Promise(resolve => pythonProcess.stdout.on("close", resolve));

    console.log("Data send back from python script:", data.toString());
    res.json({ message: "Python finished", data: data });
});
```

This will wait to add any new data to a variable, then wait for the process to end. Once the process ends, it will print the accumulated data and send it back to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!
Yes. That makes sense as you've described it. [facepalm]

I edited my code as you suggested and I've definitely made progress as the errors are now different (always a step in the right direction I've found).

However, the script still crashes at the same point. 

I've updated my post with the developments and new errors.